# Using OpenERP as users and employees management backend

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

I am trying to query OpenERP objects using xml-rpc.net from ASP.NET MVC C# to authentificate users.

```
string OERP_DB = "openerpdbname";
        string OERP_USER = "user";
        string OERP_PASSWORD = "password";

        IOpenERPLogin OpenERPAccess = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IOpenERPLogin>();
        int UserID = OpenERPAccess.Login(OERP_DB, OERP_USER, OERP_PASSWORD);


        String[] condition = new String[] { "login", "=", "someusername" };
        ArrayList lstFilters = new ArrayList();
        lstFilters.Add(condition);

        IOpenErp OpenERPOperations = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IOpenErp>();
        var ids = OpenERPOperations.search(OERP_DB, UserID, OERP_PASSWORD, "res.users", "search", lstFilters.ToArray());

        ArrayList fieldsToRead = new ArrayList();
        fieldsToRead.Add("id");
        fieldsToRead.Add("partner_id");
        fieldsToRead.Add("login");
        fieldsToRead.Add("password");
        fieldsToRead.Add("user_email");
        fieldsToRead.Add("company_id");
        fieldsToRead.Add("company_ids");
        fieldsToRead.Add("signature");
        fieldsToRead.Add("menu_id");
        fieldsToRead.Add("groups_id");
        fieldsToRead.Add("login_date");
        fieldsToRead.Add("name");
        fieldsToRead.Add("active");
        var oerp_results = OpenERPOperations.read(OERP_DB, UserID, OERP_PASSWORD, "res.users", "read", ids.ToArray(), fieldsToRead.ToArray());
```

The thing is that i was reading through documentation but didnt understood how can i get object attributes for a specific object like users.

There is a web service CRUD example for res.partners but not for anything else.

Is there a resource where i can get more into working with objects of OpenERP, like understanding the concepts behind res.xxxxxx and other object types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the list of fields available on a given OpenERP model, your best source of information is the source code of the corresponding OpenERP module.

You should quickly read the basics of how OpenERP models are constructed (a `_columns` dict declaring the various fields in the model class):

- Read the quick description of the API and field types in the [OpenERP Technical Memento](https://www.openerp.com/files/memento/), if not done yet
- Browse the more complete description of the [OpenERP module structure and model definitions](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/api_models/), and the [API](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/api_models/)

Then you can start to browse the code, either offline after grabbing a copy of the source, or via Launchpad's web UI ([server 7.0](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/7.0/files), [addons 7.0](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0/files))

Now if your needs include programmatic/dynamic access to the definition of a given model, you need to dive deeper into the API, specifically the [`fields_get`](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/api_models/#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.fields_get) method.

One useful source of inspiration could be the numerous **OpenERP client libraries** who probably try to accomplish tasks similar to what you will want to do. Some examples in Python: [the official openerp-client-lib](https://github.com/OpenERP/openerp-client-lib) and [ERPeek](https://github.com/florentx/erppeek), and one in Ruby: [OOOR](https://github.com/akretion/ooor)

Comment: I found a very simple way to get columns for now by browsing in to "OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\base\" but i dont think this is enough for long-term so thank you for your detailed answer.